# App turns grey after Splashscreen on some Samsung Devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

We received a bug report for an App, where the app transitions to a grey screen after displaying the Splashscreen on certain Samsung Galaxy devices and therefore the App cannot be used, since the Login/Home Screens are not shown afterwards (see attached image below). One specific device we got told is the following:

Samsung Galaxy Note 10 - Android Version 10 - One UI Version 2.5

The device hasn't enabled Darkmode or any other settings like eye comfort shield. Also Power saving mode is turned off.

Has anyone experienced similar issues and found solutions for it or might it even be a bug from the Samsung Software or in the One UI version? I would be thankful for any tips or help how i might be able to reproduce and/or fix this issue!

Thanks in advance.

[image: Grey Screen the App Transitions to after Splash Screen]

Comment: Is your Login/Home Screens a full screen activity?

Comment: @Nitish Yes, they are full screen activities.

Comment: Try removing the full screen from the activities, I also faces the similar issue(screen shows but no static text was visible), on samsung s9 - android 10, galaxy fold, and most of the huawie devices.  Issue only occurs when user has hidden bottom bar(back button menu) and app runs in full screen. Disabling full screen activity fixed the issue in my case.  I couldn't find the reason for the this, I tried raising issue a huawie(as that was my major devices with issue) but was marked a infeasible as it no longer support google.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try removing full screen from the activities and update the question as soon as we get feedback if the changes worked.

Comment: @Nitish you were right! the full screen activites were causing this problem, could you please add an answer to my question, so i'll be able to set it as accepted answer (and hopefully reward you with the bounty). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above issue is caused by running the app in full screen mode on OneUI and EMUI devices.
Devices affected: Samsung s9 - android 10, galaxy fold, and most of the huawie devices(p10,p20,p30).

There are 2 factors which causes this issue.

1. Navigation Bar disable
2. App Theme set to Full Screen

**Disabling the Full Screen Activites from the app should fix this issue.**

Unfortunately, there is no specific reason/resolve for this bug yet. I tried raising bug at EMUI but was marked infeasible as it no longer support Android , and there is no response Samsung.